# Como se chamam as pessoas ou animais que têm hipertireoidismo?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

> Gatos _____ são agitados.

Hipertireoidoicos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) dá-te não uma, não duas, mas quatro alternativas, parecendo implicitamente preferir ***hipertireóidico***, já que as outras três simplesmente remetem para esta. Passo a citar (desabreviando algumas abreviações):

> **hipertireoídico** *adj.* mesmo que *hipertireóidico*
>   **hipertireóidico** *adj.* relativo a ou que apresenta hipertireoidismo; hipertireoídico, hipertiroídico, hipertiróidico ʘ ETIM *híper-* + *tireóide* + *-ico*; ver *tir(e/o)-*
>   [...]
>   **hipertiroídico** *adj.* mesmo que *hipertireóidico*
>   **hipertiróidico** *adj.* mesmo que *hipertireóidico*

Comment: Na verdade, eu tenho um gato assim. Mas é velhinho. Precisa tomar remédio duas vezes ao dia.

Comment: @Lambie, e eu que nem cheguei a ver o que é isso do hipertireoidismo! :)

Comment: @Lambie Eu também tenho um gato velhinho hipertireóidico. Foi por causa dele que fiz a pergunta. :)

Comment: @Detached Laconian Ah sim. Quando são jovens, existem, outros tratamentos. Eu já tenho uma têcnica para administrar o remédio. O gosto é horrivel mas misturado com caldo de peru (rsrs), o mau gosto é bem menor. Ele fica com o olho em mim quando vai chegando a hora....Também, ele insiste em beber água na banheira. Credo, já virei escrava desse bichinho. :) Nem consigo pronunciar esse adjetivo sem hesitar....nem em inglês ou português. :)